# Go to new URL when select_tag changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This ought to be very simple in Rails, but I'm still learning...

My code

```
Sort by <%= select_tag :sort, options, :onchange => "google.com" %>
```

should redirect to a page (google is just being used as a placeholder) when the criterion for sorting is changed.

In case it matters, it'll just be going to the same page, but with ?sort=*sort type* appended.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about calling a js function through the onchange attribute?

```
Sort by <%= select_tag :sort, options, :onchange=>'myFunc(this.value)' %>
```

The js might be something like:

```
function myFunc(value) {
  window.location = "http://www.mydomain.com/myapp/mycontroller/myaction?sort="+value
}
```

Comment: That works - thank you!  It'd be nicer if I could do that without Javascript, though; I guess there isn't a simple way to do it with just Ruby/Rails?

Comment: If you want to write only ruby, you might use something like :onchange=>remote_function(:url=>{:action=>:myaction}, :with=>"'sort='+this.value"), but that's still going to generate javascript, and you'd have to add logic to your controller to handle the resulting ajax call, so going this route would be rather more complex.